Evaluate or estimate $\int_{8}^{27}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{x}}$ without a calculator in a fast way
In a fast way and without a calculator, I need to evaluate the following integral or just estimate it in a way that will lead to the correct answer.

$$\begin{align}\\&
\text{What is the value of}\,\int_{8}^{27}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{x}}\,?\\&
\\&
\text{(A) }1\\&
\\&
\text{(B) }6\log\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\bigg)\\&
\\&
\text{(C) }6\log\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\bigg)-10\sqrt{2}+12\sqrt{3}\\&
\\&
\text{(D) }6\log\bigg({\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1}}\bigg)\\&
\\&
\text{(E) }3-10\sqrt{2}+12\sqrt{3}+6\log\bigg({\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1}}\bigg)\\&
\end{align}$$

My Attempt:
Let $u=x^{1/6}\implies x=u^6 \implies \mathrm{d}x=6u^5\mathrm{d}u$
Since $x=u^6,\,\,\,\,\, x^{1/2}=u^3\,\,\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\,x^{1/3}=u^2$
Consider the indefinite integral
$$\begin{align}\\&
\int\frac{6u^5}{u^3-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\&
\\&
=6\int\frac{u^5}{u^2(u-1)}\,\mathrm{d}u\\&
\\&
=6\int\frac{u^3}{u-1}\,\mathrm{d}u\\&
\\&
=6\int \bigg(\,\underset{\text{obtained by long division}}{\underbrace{u^2+u+1+\frac{1}{u-1}}}\,\bigg)\,\mathrm{d}u\\&
\\&
=6\bigg(\frac{u^3}{3}+\frac{u^2}{2}+u+\log(u-1)\bigg)\\&
\\&
= 2u^3+3u^2+6u+6\log(u-1)
\end{align}$$
Substitute $x$ back:
$$\begin{align}\\&
=2\sqrt{x}+3\sqrt[3]{x}+6\sqrt[6]{x}+6\log(\sqrt[6]{x}-1)\\&
\\&
\end{align}$$
Plugging the limits: $x=8$ to $x=27$:
$$\bigg(\text{some mess}\bigg)-\bigg(\text{some other mess}\bigg)=\bigg(\text{Hmmm, better to estimate?}\bigg)$$
I failed to evaluate.

Another Attempt:
I know, for convergent integrals, it is true (for some accuracy) that:
$$\large\boxed{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\text{ d}x \approx \frac{b-a}{4}\bigg(f(a)+2f\bigg(\frac{a+b}{2}\bigg)+f(b)\bigg)}$$
We have
$$f(a)=f(8)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}+\sqrt[3]{8}}\approx\frac{1}{2.8+2}\approx\frac{1}{4.8}$$
and
$$f(b)=f(27)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{27}+\sqrt[3]{27}}\approx\frac{1}{5.2+3}\approx\frac{1}{8.2}$$
and
$$f\bigg(\frac{a+b}{2}\bigg)=f\bigg(\frac{35}{2}\bigg)=\frac{1}{\text{I do not know how to estimate this}}$$
So I filed in this attempt, too.

With some trials, I concluded that the answer must be $\boxed{\text{(E)}}$.

I need to solve it without a calculator in a fast (or fastest) way.

Your help is appreciated. THANKS!

Don't turn it back into $x$, evaluate it from $u=\sqrt2$ to $u=\sqrt3$

Why did you stop in the first attempt?? The mess isn't actually that much of a mess... In particular, note that you can simplify $\sqrt{8}, \sqrt[3]{8}, \sqrt[6]{8}, \sqrt{27}, \sqrt[3]{27}, \sqrt[6]{27}$ considerably.

@Empy2 I know that. It should be
$$2u^3+3u^2+6u+6\log(u-1)\bigg|_{u=\sqrt{2}}^{u=\sqrt{3}}$$
which is
$$\bigg(6\sqrt{3}+9+6\sqrt{3}+6\log(\sqrt{3}-1)\bigg)-\bigg(4\sqrt{2}+6+6\sqrt{2}+\log(\sqrt{2}-1)\bigg)$$
which in turn equal to $\text{(E)}$,
or, without simplifying, one can realise that the $\log$ terms can be combined with
$$\log(a)-\log(b)=\log\bigg(\frac{a}{b}\bigg)$$
which appears in $\text{(E)}$.
But that is tedious, because we have around $4$ minutes per problem.

@IzaakvanDongen See my comment to Empy2. That is only lengthy. Can we do it faster?

@Hussain-Alqatari from the term $6\log(u-1)$ you can verify the answer is $(D)$ or $(E)$ (as $6\left(\log(\sqrt3-1)-\log(\sqrt2-1)\right)=6\log(\dfrac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt2-1})$. Since there are other terms ($2u^3+3u^2+6u$), the choice $(E)$ makes much more sense.

By the way, when you reached $$2u^3+3u^2+6u+6\log(u-1)\bigg|_{u=\sqrt{2}}^{u=\sqrt{3}}$$
To reduce the consumed time in writing you can write,
$$2(\sqrt3^3-\sqrt2^3)+3(\ldots)$$
Or more directly, $$2(3\sqrt3-2\sqrt2)+\ldots$$

Multiple choice questions are annoying, and any question that says "in a fast way" is doubly annoying. I don't like being annoyed. There's some ugly function I don't want to think about. I'd pick a nice value of x about halfway between the limits of integration (x=16 works ok), estimate the area of that single rectangle, and then compare that estimate for the integral to the answer choices. I know $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}$, and $e$ to two decimal places. I can use that knowledge without a calculator. I'd get the correct answer and no longer be annoyed.

@MarcShelikoff sounds you have a good idea. But I did not fully understand it. Could you please share it in more detail? Thanks.

Evaluating $2\sqrt{x}+3\sqrt[3]{x}+6\sqrt[6]{x}+6\log(\sqrt[6]{x}-1)$ at $x=27$ we get $$2\sqrt{27}+3\sqrt[3]{27}+6\sqrt[6]{27}+6\ln(\sqrt[6]{27}-1)$$
As $27=3^3$ , we have $\sqrt{27}=\sqrt{3^3}=3\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt[6]{27}=\sqrt[6]{3^3}=\sqrt{3}$. Thus, $$2\sqrt{27}+3\sqrt[3]{27}+6\sqrt[6]{27}+6\ln(\sqrt[6]{27}-1)=6\sqrt{3}+9+6\sqrt{3}+6\ln(\sqrt{3}-1)$$
Similarly, at $x=8$ we get $$2\sqrt{8}+3\sqrt[3]{8}+6\sqrt[6]{8}+6\ln(\sqrt[6]{8}-1)=4\sqrt{2}+6+6\sqrt{2}+6\ln(\sqrt{2}-1)$$
It is clear that doing the difference of this two quantities we get answer $(E)$.

For a multiple choice question, an exact answer isn't required. A very rough estimate using numerical integration may be performed using the midpoint rule with one rectangle. This is the area of a single rectangle placed with a width determined by the limits of integration and a height found by the function evaluated at the midpoint of the region of integration. The midpoint is $x=\frac{8+27}{2}=17.5$.
$$\int_{8}^{27}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{x}} \approx (19)\frac{1}{\sqrt{17.5}-\sqrt[3]{17.5}} $$
Because it's an estimate anyway, select a number nearby that's easier to work with, like 16. Some trial and error or a quick halfway guess can approximate $\sqrt[3]{16}\approx 2.5$.
$$\int_{8}^{27}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{x}} \approx (19)\frac{1}{\sqrt{16}-\sqrt[3]{16}} \approx (19)\frac{1}{4-2.5} \approx \frac{18}{\frac{3}{2}}\approx 12$$
All five potential answers should be compared to 12.
This immediately eliminates answer choice A.
Many students know $\sqrt{2}\approx 1.4, \sqrt{3}\approx 1.7$, and $e\approx 2.7$. Exponents are easier than logarithms. For answer choices B and D, divide by 6 and use the exponential function.
$$e^{\frac{12}{6}}=e^{2}\approx(2.7)^{2}\approx 7$$
These choices are now:
$$\text{(B) }\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \approx 7? \\ \text{(B) }\frac{3}{2} \approx 49? \text{ No. }\\ \text{(D) }\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1} \approx 7? \\ \text{(D) }\frac{0.7}{0.4} \approx 7? \text{ No. }$$
For choice C:
$$\text{(C) } 6\log\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\bigg)-10\sqrt{2}+12\sqrt{3} \approx 12? \\
\text{(C) } 6\log\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\bigg)-14+12(1.7) \approx 12? \\
\text{(C) } 6\log\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\bigg)-14+20 \approx 12? \\
\text{(C) } 6\log\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\bigg) \approx 6? \\
\text{(C) } \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \approx e? \\
\text{(C) } \frac{3}{2} \approx 7? \text{ No.}
$$
This leaves choice E by elimination, but it is easily confirmed using work that's already been completed:
$$\text{(E) } 3-10\sqrt{2}+12\sqrt{3}+6\log\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\bigg) \approx 12? \\
\text{(E) } 3-14+20+6\log\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\bigg) \approx 12? \\
\text{(E) } 6\log\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\bigg) \approx 3? \\
\text{(E) } \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1} \approx e^{\frac{1}{2}}? \\
\text{(E) } \frac{0.7}{0.4} \approx e^{\frac{1}{2}}? \\
\text{(E) } \bigg(\frac{7}{4}\bigg)^2 \approx e? \\
\text{(E) } \frac{49}{16} \approx 2.7? \text{ Good estimate.}\\
$$
This is a lengthy answer on paper or on the screen, but in the context of an exam solution for a multiple-choice question, plopping a rectangle on the thing would be the fastest method of getting to the correct answer for this particular question for many people.

In the $u$-integral, substituting $u\to\dfrac1u$ produces an integrand with a simple partial fraction expansion, namely
$$\int_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt3} \frac{6u^3}{u-1} \, du \stackrel{u\to\tfrac1u}= \int_\tfrac1{\sqrt3}^\tfrac1{\sqrt2} \frac{6}{(1-u)u^4} \, du \\
= 6 \int_\tfrac1{\sqrt3}^\tfrac1{\sqrt2} \left(\frac1u + \frac1{u^2} + \frac1{u^3} + \frac1{u^4} + \frac1{1-u}\right) \, du$$
which follows from noticing e.g.
$$\frac1{(1-u)u^4} = \frac{(1-u)+u}{(1-u)u^4} = \frac1{(1-u)u^3} + \frac1{u^4}$$

Note that $\large{f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt[3]{x}}}$ is a decreasing function on $\large[8,27]$.
We have $\Large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{27}-\sqrt[3]{27}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{25}-\sqrt[3]{27}}=\frac{1}{5-3}=\frac{1}{2}}$
Therefore,
$$\Large{\int}>(27-8)\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)\,\implies\boxed{\int>9.5}$$

$\text{Option (A)}=1<9.5$

$\text{Option (B)}=6\log\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\bigg)<6\log(e)=6<9.5$
$$\bigg[\text{because }\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}<\frac{3}{2}<e\bigg]$$

$\text{Option (C)}=6\log\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\bigg)-10\sqrt{2}+12\sqrt{3}\approx3\log\big(\frac{3}{2}\big)-14.1+20.4\approx3(\text{less than }1)-14.1+20.4$
$\approx(\text{less than }3)+6.3<9.3<9.5$
$$\big[\text{here we used log properties, }\sqrt{2}\approx1.4\text{ and }\sqrt{3}\approx1.7\big]$$

$\text{Option (D)}=6\log\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\bigg)\approx6\log\big(\frac{1.7-1}{1.4-1}\big)=6\log\big(\frac{7}{4}\big)<6\log(e)=6<9.5$
$$\bigg[\text{because }\frac{7}{4}<e\bigg]$$

We have confirmed that $\text{(A), (B), (C) and (D)}$ are all less than $9.5$, whereas $\int>9.5$. Without any further delay, we pick $\text{(E)}$ and conclude.

Having $f(27) < \frac 12$ does not imply that $\int_9^{27}f(x) dx > 9.5$

@PierreCarre It does, since $f$ is a decreasing function on $[8,27]$.

You have that $f(27) < \frac 12  < f(8)$. The value of the integral will be $(27-8) f(\xi)$ for $\xi \in (8,27)$ but nothing in your reasoning allows to conclude if $\xi < \frac 12 $ or not.

Let me reproduce your argument in a simpler example: $f(x) = 1-x$ is decreasing in $[0,1]$ and $f(1) < \frac 32$, so we conclude that $\int_0^1(1-x) dx > \frac 32$. Does this seem right?

@PierreCarre I did not say that. For your example: $f$ is a decreasing function on $[0,1]$, and $f(1)=1-1=0$, so I conclude that $\int > 0$.

what you said was actually equivalent... From $f$ being decreasing you can say that the integral is larger than $(27 - 8) f(27)$. But then you argued that since $f(27) < \frac 12$ you would have that the integral is larger than 9.5 and this is wrong. You have the inequality reversed. Your conclusion would be correct if you had $f(27) > \frac 12$.

@PierreCarre I am not arguing, I am not a mathematician. I only study maths by myself. I could be wrong. But it would be nice if you see my illustration in the following image, and comment on it. It would be beneficial if you can provide a sketch of your counterexample. Sketch will be clearer than words as my English is not that good, I am Arabic. Thanks!
https://i.sstatic.net/0khO11pC.jpg

I agree that the integral is larger than the yellow area in your sketch. The problem is that (27-8)/2 is not the yellow area, because $\frac 12$ is larger than $f(b)$.
